# Highcharts: how to remove selected annotation (which was dynamically created)?

Tags: highcharts

I have this code https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/62Lmskbx/11/ where user can draw circle, segment and arrow-segment. When each annotation is selected, there is a "delete" button available, which should normally delete the selected annotation.

But this does not works! I tried the following ways for removing them:

1 ) using `thischart.currentAnnotation.destroy()` will delete the annotation (works for all three types) but then all the further actions stops from working

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('.highcharts-popup-annotations .deletebutton')[0]
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
    function() {
     thischart.currentAnnotation.destroy(); //this stops further drawing
     thischart.annotationsPopupContainer.style.display = 'none';
   }
);
```

2 ) using deletion by ID `thischart.removeAnnotation(thischart.currentAnnotation.options.id)` does not works, since the annotations are created dynamically and they do not have IDs assigned to them.

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('.highcharts-popup-annotations .deletebutton')[0]
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
               
    thischart.removeAnnotation(thischart.currentAnnotation.options.id); //this requires elements to have IDs (which they do not have)
    thischart.annotationsPopupContainer.style.display = 'none';
  }
);
```

For the second approach, I even tried to intersect the drawing and to assign a random string as an ID (since the reason that deletion by id does not works, is because the ID is undefined). So under `navigation -> bindings` I added the object:

```
circleAnnotation: {
  start: function(e) {
    var navigation = this.chart.options.navigation;             
    return this.chart.addAnnotation(
      Highcharts.merge({
        id: randomStr() //this is a method that generates random string
      },
      navigation
      .annotationsOptions,
      navigation
      .bindings
      .circleAnnotation
      .annotationsOptions
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The both approaches are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a direct annotation object to the `removeAnnotation` method:

```
thischart.removeAnnotation(thischart.currentAnnotation);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5ycf3s4o/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#removeAnnotation